# Visual Studio 2017 Cannot Modify - Restart Required

Tags: visual-studio

I have been trying to update and modify my Visual Studio 2017 for 2 days now, but each time I run the Visual Studio Installer, I get this message:

> "A restart is required. If needed, any remaining setup will resume
>   after the restart."

Obviously I restarted about 10 times...

Any idea what I must delete where to get rid of any temp garbage that is hindering my attempts to modify my installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found a working solution!

**It is a script one runs with PowerShell, that resets the state.**

So, for anyone else with the same issue, I hope this helps:

https://gist.github.com/heaths/1d0658c6903871e09b72395c9ab44db1#file-reset-instancestate-ps1

Comment: How does it work? I would really love if you could help me to use it.

Comment: @Revious Apologies for the late reply. Simply run the script in PowerShell

Comment: Using VS2019 here but I've got the same issue. Powershell script Reset-InstanceState.ps1 didn't fix it. Ran the script twice and rebooted each time.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue while installing Visual Studio 2019. I tried the PowerShell script proposed by @onmyway, to no avail.

Naturally, as with any simple problem in Windows, the fix is to manually edit the Windows Registry

It appears the installation may leave some stale keys behind. Remove the following keys from the registry according to your platform:

```
32Bit: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup\Reboot

64Bit: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup\Reboot
```

This immediately fixed my installation, and Visual Studio 2019 was able to start without further rebooting. I cannot promise that this will fix the issue for VS2017 users, but I leave this here for future readers.

Credit goes to Matt Cavallari from [this forum thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/576720/stuck-in-restart-required.html).

Comment: I only saw the Reboot key under the `WOW6332Node` path.  Removing it fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've stopped the setup in half-way as same thing happened to me when I stopped the setup in half way. So I uninstalled the download and started downloading component by component which worked.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. My installation did complete, however, this issue occurred after an update. I really don't want to uninstall and re-install... :D