# Error during setup of VSix of Microsoft Live share extension in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio

Microsoft VSIX Installer is not able to update Microsoft Live share extension.
I obtain the following error:

```
setup instance 1587ffb2 requires a reboot. Reboot the machine and try again.
```

Reboot of the PC didn't solve the problem.

This is the log file content:

```
25/08/2020 12:09:16 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
25/08/2020 12:09:16 - -------------------------------------------
25/08/2020 12:09:16 - vsixinstaller.exe version:
25/08/2020 12:09:16 - 16.7.3069
25/08/2020 12:09:16 - -------------------------------------------
25/08/2020 12:09:16 - Command line parameters:
25/08/2020 12:09:16 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\vsixinstaller.exe,/appidinstallpath:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe,/skuName:Pro,/skuVersion:15.0.28307.1234,/appidname:Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017,/culture:en-US,/noep,C:\TEMP\VSIXhnphjfgh.vsix
25/08/2020 12:09:16 - -------------------------------------------
25/08/2020 12:09:16 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
25/08/2020 12:09:16 - -------------------------------------------
25/08/2020 12:09:17 - Setup instance 1587ffb2 requires a reboot. Reboot the machine and try again.
25/08/2020 12:09:17 - System.InvalidOperationException: Setup instance 1587ffb2 requires a reboot. Reboot the machine and try again.
   in VSIXInstaller.SetupExtensions.GetLaunchableInstances(IQuery query)
   in VSIXInstaller.SupportedSKUs.EnumerateIsolatedInstalls(Action`1 callback)
   in VSIXInstaller.SupportedSKUs.AddInstalledLocationBasedSKUs(IntPtr userToken)
   in VSIXInstaller.SupportedSKUs.InitializeSupportedSKUs(IntPtr userToken)
   in VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.InitializeSupportedSKUs(ICommandLineData cmdLineData, IntPtr duplicatedUserToken)
   in VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   in VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
   in System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   in System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved following this suggestions
[Visual Studio 2017 Cannot Modify - Restart Required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42849942/visual-studio-2017-cannot-modify-restart-required)

Credit goes to Matt Cavallari from this
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/576720/stuck-in-restart-required.html
and Alter Igel